# Discover locally running WCF from WP7

Tags: wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, service-discovery

I have a WCF service running inside Windows Service and it is located on my local network. What I want is to be able to discover WCF from my Silverlight app on my WP7 (on the same network).

I know there a Discovery feature in WCF, however it requires to UDP, which is not supported on WP7. So are there any other ways to discover local WCF?

I also do not know prior to launching WCF the IP address of the WCF service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with, is to use Sockets as on WP7 they support multicast.
So set up would like this:

- Desktop service - Windows Service hosting WCF and small Socket app
  which listens on specific port.
- WP7 client - before connecting to WCF
  a broadcast would be sent using Sockets to find out an IP address of
  the machine which runs WCF, when got a response connect to WCF.

Answer (score 1):

For a WCF Service to be referenced in a WP7 project the WCF Service **MUST** be a BasicEndpoint

Comment: Yea, I am aware of that, that is why I looking for some other way to discover WCF.

Comment: There is no other way. Basic EndPoint for WCF and if that doesn't work you need to implement Push Notifications

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a basic endpoint that exposes a kind of catalog service. It doesn't have to implement UDDI but it could be a custom protocol to suit your needs and return addresses of web services.

This way you only need to know a single address. Of course you can cache returned addresses and query the catalog service only when you are not able to connect.

Comment: I have thought of this, but unfortunately there is no possibility to install that kind of service.

Comment: The service does not have to be a WCF service. It can be a file located at a well-know place (file share, ftp)

Comment: That is a good point. However the network will be a home network, so the user will the one who installs the software and prior to that I won't know what is their local IP address.

Comment: During setup you (the setup) will know the name of the machine/ip address. It is not that strange to have the user note the name/address and having to enter the address on other machines. That is the cost of  not starting a service that broadcasts information.